# Output troubles in Debug Console of Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I avoid the grouping of identicals lines in the Debug Console ?
For example I get

```
 _
| |\
|_| \
4    |
```

and I want

```
 _
| |\
|_| \
     |
     |
     |
     |
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was just added in the November 2020 releaase.

> Debug Console: collapse identical lines
>
> The Debug Console now collapses identical output and shows the number
> of occurrences. This feature makes it much easier to grasp repetitive
> program output.

A setting is being added to v1.54 to toggle collapsing identical lines on/off:

`debug.console.collapseIdenticalLines`

> We have introduced a setting `debug.console.collapseIdenticalLines`.
> This setting controls if the debug console should collapse identical
> lines and show a number of occurrences with a badge. Default is to
> collapse.

Comment: Thanks you !  This feature may be interesting sometimes, but not for me today !

Comment: You tell me "You may have to file an issue asking for a setting to turn off collapsing.", how can I do that ?

Comment: To file an issue, go to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue `New Issue` button.

Comment: Ok, thank you. When I think of the troubles I get, they are not very important, (I can use externalTerminal) but it could be usefull to manage the feature.